# What does "usages" means in the closing dialog moderators see?

Tags: support, moderator-tools

When I vote to close a question as duplicate on *Drupal Answers*, where I am moderator, I see a dialog box similar to the following one.

[image: Drupal Answers]

On *Meta Stack Overflow*, for example, the dialog box for closing a question as duplicate is slightly different.

[image: Meta Stack Overflow]

The difference is that I don't read the number of usages, here on this very site.

What does the number of usages mean?

Comment: It's not specific to moderators. The first type of dialog will appear on any question that doesn't yet have any duplicate close votes.

Comment: Oh... I was thinking it would be the reputation to make the difference, but clearly it should not. I didn't think of the question not having closing votes. Still, I am not sure to which _usages_ the dialog box is referring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"N usages"* here means *"This post was used as the duplicate of N closed posts"*